# Двумерный массив, обращение к элементам

Tags: perl

Подскажите как получить доступ к элементам массива, если я записываю его как свойство класса

```
sub new {
my ($class_name, $arr_elem) =  @_;
my $self = {};
$self->{elem} = ( [1, 2, 3, 4], [4, 3, 2, 1] );
print $self->{elem};
print ${$self->{elem}[0]}[0];
bless $self, matrix;
return $self;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$self->{elem}[0][0]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
bless $self, matrix;
```

1)Для начала бы неплохо было заменить matrix на $class_name, иначе это даже работать не будет.

2)Если хотите занести многомерный массив в $self->{elem}, то надо использовать [], а не ().

```
$self->{elem} = [ [1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8] ];
say $self->{elem}[0][0]; # выведет 1
# и для лучшего понимания сути:
use Data::Dumper;
say Dumper($self);
```